# How to cite getting both a footnote (end of page) and a bibliography (end of document)?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, footnotes

I'm writing a document where I have to cite something. What I need is:

1. once a short version within the footer as a footnote at the end of the page
2. once both a short and a full version within the bibliography at the end of the document

How can I solve this matter?

How I need the footnote to look:

[image: How I need the footnote to look]

How I need the bibliography to look:

[image]

My current latex document:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[%
backend=bibtex
,style=numeric-comp
,sorting=none
,sortcites=true
,block=none
,indexing=false
,citereset=none
,isbn=true
,url=true
,doi=true
,natbib=true
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\lhead{}
\rhead{\leftmark}
\lfoot{}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\cfoot{\empty}

\pagenumbering{Roman}

\title{}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

    \maketitle

    \thispagestyle{empty}

    \newpage

    \thispagestyle{fancy}

    \section*{}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{}

    \section*{}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{}

    \newpage

    \tableofcontents
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{}

    \newpage

    \pagenumbering{arabic}

    \section{} 

    \newpage

    \section{}


        \subsection{}


        \subsection{Example}
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.\cite{wirt01}

    \newpage

        \subsection{}


        \subsection{}

    \newpage

    \section{}


    \newpage

    \pagenumbering{Roman}
    \setcounter{page}{4}    

    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Bibliopraphy}
    \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.